# openvpn: match client certificate to specific ldap user

Tags: openvpn

I'm in the process of re-configuring a openvpn setup to make it more secure.

Currently it uses only ldap authentication. I'm planning to change it to also require a client certificate.

My understanding though, is that as long as you have a valid client certificate, it won't really matter who's certificate it is.

Is there a way to have it verify that the certificate matches the ldap user?

This way, if a hacker managed to obtain a certificate, it wouldn't really be any use to them without also having the login for the matching ldap user. Likewise, if they compromised an ldap user password, they would need one specific matching certificate, not just any valid client certificate.

At this stage I'm planning to use easy-rsa to generate the CA, Server, and Client certificates, just because I know it works, and I know how to do it.

Setting up Microsoft AD (our ldap provider) as a CA, seemed a bit complicated to attempt at this stage.

Comment: You can do any checks you want in the `client-connect` script. Just return failure (exit code other than 0) and server will drop the connection.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov This suggestion helped me get a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's helpful to anyone else. This is the client-connect script I ended up using...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "client-connect: common_name=$common_name, username=$username"

if [ "$common_name" == "$username" ]; then
  echo "Client certificate common_name matches username. Allow connection."
  exit 0
else
  echo "Client certificate common_name does not match username. Reject connection."
  exit 1
fi
```

common_name and username are environment variables automatically provided to the script by openvpn.

From https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/